# How do I access Firestore using CURL with an API Key and service account token?

Tags: firebase, curl, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access my Firestore database using cURL from a terminal session.   I have read through the REST API documentation for Firestore and the Authentication documentation for authenticating Oauth and services accounts.  I have set up a services accounts and IAM roles  in API dashboard.   I cannot  determine from the  documentation what the correct path and syntax and what do use for the API Key and the BEARER token.   For example, I am trying to receive a json response for the USER xyz, document field FNAME that is stored in a Firestore DATABASE (note - where do i find the the databaseID?) that is in PROJECT testproject.

Here is the CURL command lists in the documentation -

```
curl \
  'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%5BNAME%5D?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed

curl --request POST \
  'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta2/%5BNAME%5D:exportDocuments?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{}' \
  --compressed
```

Questions are - what do I use for the [YOUR_API_KEY] ?
What do I use for the [YOUR ACCESS  TOKEN] -

I have tried the following from credentials for a Service account that I set up

```
Service account - Key - 3......................e76
Unique ID - 1............39
```

for the API KEY and  the ACCESS TOKEN and get a 403 error  back

I also have a Oauth  credentials -

```
Client ID - 2.....113-95.......cpqrarqb.....qnrpc.apps.googleusercontent.com
Client Secret - L......lq
```

PATH

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/collectionGroups/{collectionId}/fields/{field_id}
```

Which didn't work either...

Again, I am trying to access and read and write data to my Firestore database using CURL  - as a proxy for what will be my REST API's.      Any help and assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the curl commands you have pasted I understand that you want to export your firestore collections to a Cloud Storage bucket.  Furthermore I understand you obtained the curl commands from the api [explorer](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases/exportDocuments) of the exports method.

To provide an api key value to  [YOUR_API_KEY], you first need to create an api key in your GCP project; here is the process:

1. Go to the [credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) section.
2. Click on the option at the top called 'Create Credentials'.
3. Select API key.
4. Copy and keep safe the value thrown by the Cloud Console (this is your api key).

If you want to know more about API keys, you can visit [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).

To provide an oauth token value, you can do the following:

1. You can [open](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell) Cloud Shell.
2. Run command `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`.
3. Copy and keep safe the value thrown by Cloud Shell (this is your oauth token).

Please note that there are several ways to create an oauth token but the one I specified is the fastest one. You may also use the oauth [playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to generate your token; keep in mind that the token is valid for 60 minutes.

As per the database id I have used (default) and here I include my curl statement:

```
curl --request POST \  
'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/databases/(default):exportDocuments?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \  
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \  
--header 'Accept: application/json' \  
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \  
--data '{"collectionIds":["users"],"outputUriPrefix":"gs://[BUCKET_PATH]"}' \  
--compressed
```